# Lightning data table - display fields from Apex

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have LWC component that retrieves its data from an Apex class that returns `Map<String, Object>` in order to display it later in LWC - lightning-data table.

The reason I retrieve this Map, it's that I need to get 3 different objects so I did it on one call to the server.

I made a call from LWC to the Apex class and received this structure (for the object I needed in this table) - which its an array of a custom object that has a reference to the Account Object.

[image]

In my LWC I use this code:

HTML:

```
<div class="test">
    <lightning-datatable
       data={newbArr}
       columns={columns}
       onrowselection={selectRow}
       key-field="id">
     </lightning-datatable>
   </div>
```

and in My JS:

```
columns = [
        {label : 'Select', fieldName: 'Select', wrapText: true},
        { label: 'Account Id', fieldName: 'Account_Number__c', wrapText: true },
        { label: 'Account Name', fieldName: 'Name', wrapText: true },
        { label: 'BillingCountry', fieldName: 'BillingCountry', wrapText: true },
    ];
```

And the newbArr which has the data from the screenshot above.

I can't see anything on my table.

So I tried to display the fields: Id and accountId - and it worked.

Probably because it's on the same object I retrieved.

But since I need to get the data from the lookup object I had some issues.

So I tried the dot notation because of the structure of the returned value :

```
  columns = [
            {label : 'Select', fieldName: 'Select', wrapText: true},
            { label: 'Account Id', fieldName: 'Account.Account_Number__c', wrapText: true },
            { label: 'Account Name', fieldName: 'Account.Name', wrapText: true },
            { label: 'BillingCountry', fieldName: 'Account.BillingCountry', wrapText: true },
        ];
```

But it didn't work either.

Many thanks.